# What does a=(b==c) mean in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've tried to search for the answer for the above question but wasn't able to come up with a proper formulation of it. So, what does a=(b==c); do in matlab.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know matlab, but it looks like it means 'set a=true if b is equal to c, set a to false otherwise'.

Comment: @darnhul yeah, sorry, 3rd allnighter in a row, didn't figure out to do that =|. won't happen again=)

Comment: @Flimzy you were right, it gives 1 if true, 0 if false. sry for disturbing with stupid question and thanks

Comment: -1 This is something you could investigate with a tiny amount of work and experimentation in MATLAB

Comment: this question is not related to matlab... Its logical question. Output for a will be same in all programming language.

Comment: @FahimParkar: In *all* programming languages? I doubt that...

Comment: @H.Muster : for which language you have doubt? You might try at [http://ideone.com/](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: @FahimParkar: all the languages that do not know the `==` operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator

Comment: @FahimParkar: also all the languages that struggle with vectors. e.g. b=[1 2 3 4 5 6], c=[2 2 4 4 6 6] then in MATLAB a=(b==c) will result in a=[0 1 0 1 0 1]

Comment: @Fahim Parkar: That's absolutely untrue.  Try that in BASIC.

Answer (score 4):

If you read `a=(b==c);` you will see that

`a=(b==c);` you assign `(b==c)` to `a`

`(b==c)` means `b equals c?` This wil result in `true` or `false`.

So in short you assign `true` to `a` when b equals c. If not `false` is assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

*Question:* is `b` equal to `c`?

*Answer* is in the proposition `b==c`.

*Question:* how do I store the logic value of the proposition?

*Answer:* in the variable `a = (b==c)`.